# JUnit test case using mockito

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I'm very new to junit mockito and trying to write junit test case using mockito.

Here is my method for which I have to write a junit.

```
public String getAllCookBooks(ChefService chefService, ChefApi chefApi) {
    JSONObject cookBooks = null;
    cookBooks = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray array = null;
    array = new JSONArray();

    try {
        if (null != chefService.listCookbookVersions()) {
            LOG.debug(SuccessCode.COOKBOOK_DETAILS_RETRIEVED_SUCCCESS
                    .getSuccessCode()
                    + "::"
                    + SuccessCode.COOKBOOK_DETAILS_RETRIEVED_SUCCCESS
                            .getMessage());
            for (CookbookVersion cookbookVersion : chefService
                    .listCookbookVersions()) {

                JSONObject cookBooksDetails = new JSONObject();

                cookBooksDetails.put("cookbook_name",
                        cookbookVersion.getCookbookName());
                cookBooksDetails.put("cookbook_version",
                        cookbookVersion.getVersion());

                cookBooksDetails.put("name", cookbookVersion.getName());
                array.put(cookBooksDetails);
            }
        } else {
            LOG.info("no cookbook present..."
                    + ErrorCode.COOKBOOK_LIST_EMPTY_ERROR.getErrorCode()
                    + " : "
                    + ErrorCode.COOKBOOK_LIST_EMPTY_ERROR.getMessage());
            cookBooks.put("error",
                    ErrorCode.COOKBOOK_LIST_EMPTY_ERROR.getMessage());
        }
        cookBooks.put("chef_cookbooks", array);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        LOG.warn("JSON Exception "
                + ErrorCode.JSON_PARSE_ERROR.getErrorCode() + " "
                + ErrorCode.JSON_PARSE_ERROR.getMessage());
    }

    LOG.debug("cookbooks: " + cookBooks.toString());
    LOG.info("Ended getAllCookBooks method");
    return cookBooks.toString();
}
```

The method arguments passed ChefService and ChefApi are from 3rdparty api

here the call `chefService.listCookbookVersions()` will return a iterator of type CookBookVersion class like `Iterable<? extends CookbookVersion>` 
I'm not getting how to pass the ChefService mock object in the method which will return some value to compare.

Please help .

Comment: You're not using the `chefApi` parameter, which makes writing your mock easy (you only have one thing to mock), but makes your code bad (you're not using all of your parameters, so why is it there to begin with?

Comment: I don't understand the question.  Have you attempted to write your JUnit test?  What didn't work for you?  Is there something that we can look at and try to fix for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not passing anything in.  You're explicitly telling the framework that, when this particular call is invoked, then return **something**.

```
ChefService chefServiceMock = mock(ChefService.class);
// some reasonable, expected entry value
List<CookbookVersion> cookbookVersions = ...; 
when(chefServiceMock.listCookbookVersions()).thenReturn(cookbookVersions);
// You're not actually using the API object, so you can pass in null.
// It'd be wiser to remove it altogether.
String actual = testObject.getAllCookBooks(chefServiceMock, null);
```

When you're done, you'll want to ensure that it was called, so you would want to `verify` the call.

```
// later
verify(chefServiceMock).listCookbookVersions();
```

Then, **make sure** that you verify the actual result.  I've seen tests which only validate that the mocks work, but the data that was actually being generated was garbage.

Be sure that it's data you also *expect* to receive from your list of inputs from the API.

Comment: @Makato- Thanks for the reply, the method should not have unused param as u said, will remove that. The problem here is I'm not able to create a dummy value here to compare with Mockito.when() . Like List<CookbookVersion> cookbookVersions = ...

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do (most likely) is:

```
ChefService chefService = mock(ChefService.class); // create the mock
when(chefService.listCookbookVersions()).thenReturn(aListOfValues); // establish what would be returned on method call, in this case 'aListOfValues'

// you could do the same for chefApi

String result = getAllCookbooks(chefService, chefApi); // call you method

//assert something on the result
```

Comment: The issue here is I'm not able to create a value to compare. Here in when(chefService.listCookbookVersions()).thenReturn(aListOfValues); I'm not able create a dummy value to pass. to get the value we have to call 3rd party to return a List<CookbookVersion> . How can I create a dummy value here... any suggestion ?

Comment: In the example I gave you, the dummy value would be 'aListOfValues', which you have to provide (a controlled value)